# Meditation practice in the name of god

Tags: shiva, vishnu, gods, meditation, mind

we must Always keep your mind on God and be meditating in the name of god, right.  Can anyone please tell me what kind of practice is supposed to be incorporated here. should we be thinking about him, should we be worshipping him, should we be loving him without impurity, should we be bowing to him that he is above all, during meditation. I think it encompasses all these. Please let me learn more about this.

Comment: What are your goals and what do you know about Hindu philosophy is more important? What practices you do? There are thousands of meditation and suggesting one is very difficult with the description you gave.